# How to save data to database from different activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am working on one Android app, in which I've created one RegisterActivity which has 4 different fragments in tab format, so basically there are 4 different tabs in a single activity. Each tab has different fragment, so I had created different fragment activity for each fragment.

Each fragment has some user inputs, like 
1st fragment is to collect login information from user like username, password,
2nd fragment collects Personal Info like DOB, Address, Contact number & so on

Now I want to collect data from user in every fragment & I have only one signup button in last fragment, so when user insert all data correctly, & on clicking signup button I need to save data from all fragments to a database.

How can I do that?

Comment: You may not want to go about doing things this way because not all Fragments may be present and as such, the data within each fragment may not be present. Are you ensuring that your data is being passed correctly from one fragment to the next? This is a TabbedLayout so the user can move between the tabs as they wish and from what you describe, you will not have the control of flow for your registration that you need.

Comment: Somehow using Intent can pass the data in every activity?@AkiAki007

Comment: Basically for that purpose, you can define varaibles in activity and save data into that variables and in the final signup use the data from the activity variables.

Comment: Yeah!!! That's was so simple solution, Sometimes we neglect simple solutions & runs after difficult things, Thanks mate.